# Using Restkit as a subframework

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks, restkit

I have this Use case: I am making a OSX and an iOS application which need to communicate to my API by Restkit. So I created a universal framework to hold my Models and managers in one place. This Framework need a reference to the RestKit Framework. 
Here the trouble starts:

Situation:   OSX-App => My.framework => Restkit.framework

[image: Project tree]

Debuggung and building works, but archiving and deployment fails. A "dyld error message: Library not loaded" Image not found always occurred.

I stuck around with Restkit's "Installation Directory" and "Framework Installation Path" and "Copy Build Phases" to post-copy rest kit to some places.

Is there any "Best Practises" to ended Restkit (or any other framework) in a self made framework and deploy this to an OSX or iOs App? Has anybody a similar problem solved?

edit: 
The trick is to get the 'restKit' directly under ../Frameworks in the bundle. Like this: [image: Contents of bundle file]
I get this, when I add another reference to Restkit from the OSX App - So I have the Restkit references from the executable App And from my framework. Not brilliant but it works for now.

How can I copy the Restkit.Framework directly to the executables framework-folder?